# Using Generic Parameter Type in Kotlin Annotations

Tags: kotlin, generics, annotations

I'm trying to define annotation with a type parameter

```kotlin
annotation class BotCommandScopeChat<T>(
    val type: String = "chat",
    val chatId: T,
)
```

here `chatId` can be in form of `Integer` like `1234567890` or `String` like `@supergroup` 
but intellj says *Invalid type of annotation member*.

so what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin annotations can [only use the following as construction parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#constructors):

- Types that correspond to Java primitive types (Int, Long etc.)
- Strings
- Classes (`Foo::class`)
- Enums
- Other annotations
- Arrays of the types listed above

Generic types are not allowed.

In your situation you'll either have to make two constructors, one for each type:

```kotlin
annotation class BotCommandScopeChatIntId(
    val type: String = "chat",
    val chatId: Int,
)

annotation class BotCommandScopeChatStringId(
    val type: String = "chat",
    val chatId: String,
)
```

Or have two constructor parameters, one for each type:

```kotlin
annotation class BotCommandScopeChat(
    val type: String = "chat",
    val chatIdString: String? = null,
    val chatId: Int? = null,
)
```

These will have to have default parameters, else users will always have to provide one, even if they don't need to.

Or (and this would be my preference), just use a String, and convert it to an Int if necessary.

```kotlin
annotation class BotCommandScopeChat(
    val type: String = "chat",
    val chatId: String,
)
```

Comment: so generic annotations don't exist for kotlin?

Comment: If you need to specify a class as an argument of an annotation, use a Kotlin class (KClass).